# IBeam/Gateway API failing while placing in order on the /orders endpoint: Missing order parameters

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I have the following code to place an order via IBeam - i'm able to use all the other endpoints without much issues except whenever i send a request to

`http://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/account/{accountId}/orders`

i keep getting

`{'error': 'Bad Request: Missing order parameters', 'statusCode': 400}`

```
def place_stock_order(
    account_id, symbol, quantity, order_action, order_type, limit_price
):
    # Define the endpoint for placing orders
    order_endpoint = "/iserver/account/" + account_id + "/orders/whatif"

    contract_con_id = get_conid_for_symbol(symbol)

    headers = {"User-Agent": "Console", "content-type": "application/json"}

    # Define the order details
    order_details = {
        "acctId": account_id,
        "conid": "conidex = " + contract_con_id,
        "secType": "secType = " + contract_con_id + ":STK",
        "cOID": account_id + symbol + order_action + order_type,
        "orderType": order_type,
        "listingExchange": "SMART",
        "isSingleGroup": False,
        "outsideRTH": False,
        # "price": limit_price,
        "side": order_action,
        "ticker": symbol,
        "tif": "GTC",  # good till cancelled
        "referrer": account_id + symbol + order_action + order_type,
        "quantity": quantity,
        "useAdaptive": False,
        "isCcyConv": False,
        "strategy": "Adaptive",
        "strategyParameters": {"adaptivePriority": "Normal"},
    }

    orders = [order_details]

    # Send a POST request to the API to place the order
    response = requests.post(ibkr_base_url + order_endpoint, json=orders, headers=headers, verify=False)

    data = response.json()

    pprint(response.content)

    return data
```

I've tried adding nearly all the parameters mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html#tag/Order/paths/%7E1iserver%7E1account%7E1%7BaccountId%7D%7E1orders/post) but can't seem to be able to get any more info out of the service.

I get the same response if i do a cURL request against the same endpoint

```
 productionize !3 ?1  curl -X POST \                                                                                  52 ✘  3.11.3   12:15:53  
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -k \
  -d '{
    "orders": [
      {
        "conid": "0",
        "secType": "0:STK",
      }
    ]
  }' \
  "https://localhost:5001/v1/api/iserver/account/<accountidobfuscated>/orders"
{"error":"Bad Request: Missing order parameters","statusCode":400}%
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're not showing any of the relevant values here like quantity or order_type.

Answer (score 0):

`conid` needs to be a number and you are missing a string param for `conidex`.. This thing is super hard to debug. FYI. I finally got it working by going to their web client portal, running an order preview, and watching the request from the network tab.